# Generate all combinations of pairs

Tags: algorithm

How can I generate all combinations of pairings? For example if I have `1, 2, 3, 4` I want to generate

```
(1, 2), (3, 4)
(1, 3), (2, 4)
(1, 4), (2, 3)
```

My first thought was to recursively generate a pair and attempt to add pairs from the remaining numbers. However, this leads to duplicates, as `(1, 2), (3, 4)` would be generated as well as `(3, 4), (1, 2)` even if the pairs to be added were generated uniquely. I could then remove all duplicates but is there a cleaner algorithm?

My try in psuedocode:

```
add_pair(current list, remaining nums)
    generate pairs from remaining nums
    for every pair generated:
        remove numbers used in pair from remaining nums
        add pair + add_pair(current list, remaining nums) to current list
```

I am not very comfortable with recursion yet so this probably won't work. Another solution method mentioned in other places is backtracking, but I'm not sure how this would be used effectively.

Comment: How many times does `(1, 2)` appear in the output for `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`?

Comment: Are you asking for problems with a particular [tag:c++] code, or just for the general algo? If the latter, remove the c++ tag, and eventually provide some pseudo code for the stuff you've worked out already.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I think it would be 3: `(1, 2)` and the 3 rearrangements of `3, 4, 5, 6`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very common technique for avoiding duplicates in enumeration problems is to construct the partial objects (in this case, a pairing of some of the list elements) in a canonical fashion. Here, that could mean looping over the possible mates for the first element in the list and enumerating the pairings of the remaining elements. We can enumerate a pairing in only one order (pairs sorted by where their first element occurs), so there are no duplicates. In C++:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<int> IntVec;

// elems has paired elements followed by unpaired elements
// first is an iterator to the first unpaired element
void EnumeratePairings(IntVec* elems, IntVec::iterator first) {
  if (first == elems->end()) {
    // visit the pairing
    // for demonstration purposes, we print it out
    IntVec::const_iterator i(elems->begin());
    while (i != elems->end()) {
      std::printf("(%d, ", *i);
      ++i;
      if (i == elems->end()) break;
      std::printf("%d), ", *i);
      ++i;
    }
    std::printf("\n");
    return;
  }
  IntVec::iterator second(first);
  ++second;
  // make sure that there are at least two elements
  if (second == elems->end()) return;
  IntVec::iterator third(second);
  ++third;
  // for each possible pairing involving the first element,
  // enumerate the possibilities recursively
  for (IntVec::iterator j(second);
       j != elems->end();
       ++j) {
    // pair *first with *j
    std::swap(*second, *j);
    EnumeratePairings(elems, third);
    // don't undo the swap yet
    // this way, the unpaired elements are in order
    // for subsequent iterations
  }
  // restore the order of the unpaired elements
  std::rotate(second, third, elems->end());
}

int main(void) {
  IntVec elems;
  for (int i(1); i != 7; ++i) elems.push_back(i);
  EnumeratePairings(&elems, elems.begin());
}
```

Comment: So this is like generating `12 13 14 23 24 34` but with pairs instead of individual numbers?

Comment: @qwr That doesn't seem like a helpful analogy, but perhaps I'm not understanding you correctly.

Comment: hm, so my original thinking was correct? For every pair with a 1 in it, recurse and generate remaining pairs with the remaining numbers, using the first available number in the next pair?